# Intellij not detecting JAR's in Play Framework project

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I've loaded a playframework project into intellij. I have an external jar in the project (Which is in my lib folder) but for some reason intellij isn't detecting it.

The jar is also included in the SDK's for platform settings. In any other project I have in intellij it detects this JAR no problem. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see it in the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html)? Also try `File` | `Invalidate Caches`.

Comment: try to call these commands in your project directory (bash): `play clean-all; play idea`  - usually that helps

Comment: I added it to module dependencies with no luck. I also tried play clean-all , no luck. However intellij does see com.restfb.types (restfb is the jar) but none of the calsses inside of the packages.

Comment: I created a new project in intellij which add's the missing JAR but then removes all the play jars. If I rerun idea command then it adds the play framework jar's but removes my external jars... pain!

Answer (score 1):

While doing in development in idea you have to add the lib folder as a dependency to the module. It worked for me when I added the manual dependency

> File->Project Structure-> Modules -> (select your module if multiple) -> dependencies

Then I just clicked 'add' to add the lib folder. Your project would start detecting the jars.

[Intellij Documentation to add external jars](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).